# compojure stack-over-flows when editing code dynamically

Tags: clojure

I'm working on a webapp using compojure, and I used to use `lein ring server` to test my application.

As something went wrong(e.g 500 Server Error during a http request), I always edit the code while the ring server was running, and it kept dynamically re-compile when I save my changes so there's no need to restart `lein ring server`

But something went strange today. There was a file, which holds the core logic of the whole application. I designed it carefully so there was no cyclic dependency. Everything was fine as I started `lein ring server`. But soon things got weird: any update (even an addition of a single space) on that file causes the server stack-over-flows on the next http-request, and if I restart the server, every thing goes fine again, and my new code runs well. So until now, every time I need to update that file, I need to shut down the server, update the file, and then run `lein ring server` again. That's a waste of time, and I want to know what might be the reason.

The message on error shows:

```
at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6177)
at ns_tracker.dependency$transitive.invoke(dependency.clj:22)
at ns_tracker.dependency$transitive$fn__924.invoke(dependency.clj:21)
at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6022.invoke(protocols.clj:79)
at clojure.core.protocols$fn__5979$G__5974__5992.invoke(protocols.clj:13)
```

for hundreds of times with an exception of "stackoverflow".

Thanks for all of you very much

Comment: Can't know without seeing your code snippet.

Comment: All code works well, and the stack trace shows no code inside my application....

Comment: What are the versions of Clojure, Ring and Compojure?

Comment: I'm using clojure 1.5.1 with compojure 1.1.5, leiningen 1.2.2, lein-ring 0.8.5 and ring-mock 0.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is really hard to be accurate without seeing the code and the terminal, I would suggest to upgrade your lein-ring dependency to a newer version. lein-ring 0.8.5 was known to has some issues.